# Launch an other tab's using a button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-tabhost

I've created an android project with a tabhost and so on.
I can switch into the views that I want and all is OK.

Now, I want to launch an other tab by using a button...

here's my main.class :

```
public class Main extends TabActivity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("", "Welcome in Main");
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  // Le TabHost a des Tabs

    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  // TabSpec: new tab - TabSpec : setContent to the tab
    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Informations", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.database)).setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);

    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Graphiques", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart)).setContent(new Intent(this,SecondTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);

    TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");  // tid1 is firstTabSpec Id (used to access outside)
    thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("Réglages", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings)).setContent(new Intent(this,ThirdTab.class));
    tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
```

I tried to :

```
    public void secondJour(View v) {
    Log.v("", "onCLick 001");
    new Intent(this,SecondTab.class);
}
```

But it doesn't seems to run (no error but nothing new on the screen..)

Have you got a solution?

Thanks for reading!!!

Comment: can you write whole onClick method for button? THanks...

Comment: @Jim : Thanks & Done ;-) but there's nothing special! If you wanna see how I made the main method (that manage the tab's), ask me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

use the `startActivity(new Intent(this.Second.class))`

Comment: Great, Thanks, I'ts running BUT I don't see my tab's (It launch second.class without the tab's). Could I show the tab's? ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondTab.class))`

Comment: Your wrote in your list "I've created an android project with a tabhost and so on. I can switch into the views that I want and all is OK. " Why you cannot do the same with second class ? If you dont know how to create tab activity, i suggest you to read this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html